# How to add calendar events by their id and delete them by their id? (Android 4.0)

Tags: android, calendar

With this code my team mate was adding calendar events. This works without problems. The calendar events are shown in the google calendar.

```
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startInMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endInMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Raum: " + location);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,
                "Dauer der Veranstaltung: " + duration + " min" + "---|---Dozent: "
                        + organizer.trim() + "---|---Course added by UNIDATE---|");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
        ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
```

But now I want to delete these events by their id. I've used this code (among others):

```
long selectedEventId = 1;
String[] selArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(selectedEventId)};
int deleted = getContentResolver().delete(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, Events._ID + " =? ", selArgs);
```

This doesn't work. I also tried to add

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events._ID, id);
```

Comment: deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
int rows = getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);

Comment: from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html ... possibly?

Comment: I'll try now and report to you

Comment: It hasn't worked. I think the fault is made on the adding method. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you found the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to first clear the calendar events, and then add the relevant events.

Clearing the calendar events can be done by calling this:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(calendarId)});
```